# Can not copy assembly stodole.dll to file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add Microsoft Document Imaging Library in my project for OCR. but getting below error while adding COM reference.

> Can not copy assembly stodole.dll to file

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You sure it is not called `stdole.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go through the normal steps of:

- Clean the solution
- Restart Visual Studio
- Reboot the machine

Failing that make sure your build directory is not write protected and make sure you've got the correct DLL name.

Comment: Seeing Leppie's comment I suspect he is right!  I've heard of stdole at least!

Comment: After restarting although reference has been added but now I am getting below exception. I am reading text from image using Microsoft Imaging library and facing problems.